# pydev and the src directory vs. scm

Tags: eclipse, version-control, pydev

I'm trying to transition to eclipse+pydev but am having a problem importing projects under scm. My old projects (and also projects on github) don't have the "src" parent directory that pydev seems to really like.

If I use egit or subclipse to import/check out the project, the pydev environment is incomplete. If I externally check out the source and move it into place, I don't seem to be able to tell eclipse it's SCM'd.

I would think this is a FAQ, but I can't figure it out. What is the best practice to use SCM'd projects under eclipse that aren't SCM'd as *eclipse* projects.

Thanks. Kent

Comment: This is just the information I was looking for. The pydev website indicates that all python source should be in a subdirectory to utilize all features. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose the properties for the project. Then change the pydev-PYTHONPATH - remove the src entry and then add the directory of your project that contains the source.